# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g

I tried the following SQL query, but it gives me the error of missing keyword every time I try to run it.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("Select A.SAP_ID, A.NAME, A.ROOM_NO, A.BRANCH, A.YEAR, O.OUT_DATE, O.OUT_TIME "
+ "FROM (ADD_STU A INNER JOIN OUT_TABLE O)"
+ "ON (A.SAP_ID=O.SAP_ID) "
+ "WHERE A.SAP_ID=? AND OUT_DATE=?");
pstmt.setString(1,jTextField3.getText());
pstmt.setString(2,date);
rs1=pstmt.executeQuery();
```

What is the missing keyword?

Comment: You miss a blank at the end of the string `+ "FROM (ADD_STU A INNER JOIN OUT_TABLE O)"`

Comment: Remove the parentheses around the `table JOIN table` clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PreparedStatement pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("Select A.SAP_ID, A.NAME, A.ROOM_NO, A.BRANCH, A.YEAR, O.OUT_DATE, O.OUT_TIME "
  + "FROM ADD_STU A "
  + "  INNER JOIN OUT_TABLE O ON A.SAP_ID = O.SAP_ID "
  + "WHERE A.SAP_ID=? AND OUT_DATE=?");
```

The problem was with the parentheses `()`

Comment: THANKS FOR THE SOLUTION, REMOVING THE PARENTHESIS SOLVED MY PROBLEM.